# Implementing a String Split() Operator in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'd like to be able to interpret incoming characters and "split" them (in this case, by the space character).

```
var incomingCharacters = "This is a test".ToCharArray().ToObservable();

// Yields a sequence of words - "This", "is", "a", "test"
var incomingWords = incomingCharacters.Split(' ');
```

I made an operator to do this, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

```
public static IObservable<string> Split(this IObservable<char> incomingCharacters, char s)
{
    var wordSeq = Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
        {
            // Create an inner sequence to look for word separators; publish each word to the
            // "outer sequence" as it is found
            var innerSeq = incomingCharacters
                .Concat(Observable.Return(s))           // Enables the last word to be processed
                .Scan(new StringBuilder(), (builder, c) =>
                    {
                        if (c != s)
                        {
                            builder.Append(c);
                            return builder;
                        }

                        // We encountered a "split" character; publish the current completed word
                        // and begin collecting a new one
                        observer.OnNext(builder.ToString());
                        return new StringBuilder();
                    });

            innerSeq.Subscribe(list => { });

            return Disposable.Empty;
    });

    // Return the outer sequence
    return wordSeq;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use the "push-based" Rx option here? You've got a  full string, just split it via plain-old LINQ?

Comment: Sorry, I just put the full string in to facilitate the example - in the real world I wanted to be able to handle characters coming in one at a time . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way simpler way to do this using `Buffer`:

```
public static IObservable<string> Split(
          this IObservable<char> incomingCharacters, 
          char sep)
{
    // Share a single subscription
    var oneSource = incomingCharacters.Publish().RefCount();

    // Our "stop buffering" trigger will be the separators
    var onlySeparators = oneSource
        .Where(c => c == sep);

    return oneSource
        // buffer until we get a separator
        .Buffer(onlySeparators)
        // then return a new string from the buffered chars
        .Select(carr => new string(carr.ToArray()));        
}
```

Test:

```
void Main()
{
    var feeder = new Subject<char>();   
    var query = feeder.Split(' ');

    using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        foreach(var c in "this should split words on spaces ".ToCharArray())
        {
            feeder.OnNext(c);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }       
}
```

Output:

```
this 
should 
split 
words 
on 
spaces
```

EDIT: A basic `BufferUntil` implementation

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IObservable<IList<T>> BufferUntil<T>(
         this IObservable<T> source, 
         Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var singleSource = source.Publish().RefCount();
        var trigger = singleSource.Where(predicate);
        return singleSource.Buffer(trigger);
    }

    public static IObservable<string> Split(
       this IObservable<char> incomingCharacters, 
       char sep)
    {
        return incomingCharacters
             .BufferUntil(c => c == sep)
             .Select(carr => new string(carr.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is important to mention that this subscribes to `incomingCharacters` multiple times which may cause unexpected side effects for both hot and cold observables.  For example, write your test using `"this should split words on spaces ".ToCharArray().ToObservable().Split(' ')` instead of using a `Subject`.

Comment: @Brandon Ah, crap, I'm always forgetting my publishes...thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: :) Otherwise it is a clever solution.  I always struggle with using Buffer properly.

Comment: @Brandon LeeCampbell has an awesome blog post about the varieties of `Window`, `Buffer`, and `GroupJoin`: http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2011/03/rx-part-9join-window-buffer-and-group.html

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!  My mind is blown a little.  It makes me wish the Buffer() method had an overload to just take in the boolean filter directly (in this case, something like .BufferUntil(c => c == sep)).  This opened my eyes about what you can do with the Buffer method.  Thanks again!

Comment: @blaster no problem! `BufferUntil` is actually a fairly easy thing to derive from this - I'll add it in as an edit